How to examine a dynamical system's behaviour at infinity?
I have a dynamical system defined by the following system of differential equations:
$\begin{cases} \dot{x}_1= f_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n, \lambda),\\ \vdots \\ \dot{x}_n = f_n(x_1, \ldots, x_n, \lambda). \end{cases}$
In my case, functions $f_i$ are nonlinear polynomials of $\{x_i\}$ ($n=6$, but I don't think it really matters). I am not providing  functions $f_i$ here explicitly because they are too massive.
By introducing $\lambda$ as an argument of functions $f_i$ I've tried to show that these functions also depend on some set of constant parameters $\lambda = \{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots \}$ which appear only as coefficients of $x_i$.
The typical function might look like this: $f_i = 4x_1 x_3 + 6\lambda_2 x_4^3 x_5 + 12\lambda_3(x_6 - x_1) + \ldots $
My goal is to find such limitations on parameters (for example, $\lambda_i > 3$ or $\lambda_i = 2 \lambda _j$) that guarantee all $x_i$ to be finite as the time $t$ goes for an arbitrary initial values of $x_i(t)$. One can say that it's the same as all trajectories stay bounded as $t \to \infty$.
To do so, I've searched for fixed points at infinity. By intoducing the change of variables $x_i \rightarrow \tilde{x}_i = \dfrac{1}{x_i} $ I get a new dynamical system, where $x_i$ is replaced with $\tilde{x}_i$. Letting $\tilde{x_i} = 0$ is the same as $x_i$ being at infinity, so I try to find fixed points and then examine them on stability (by finding a linearized matrix consisting of first derivatives, finding its eigenvalues etc). If a fixed point is unstable, which means no ${\lambda_i}$ value can make it stable, that's okay; otherwise, I must find such $\lambda$-parameters values that make this point stable, and restrict such values.
However, this approach has significant disadvantages. Such variable change makes the dynamical system much more complicated; finding all fixed points and proving that there are no more of them left seems impossible.
The origin of the problem is from physics: such dynamical system appears from equations of motion of some gravitational Lagrangian (not General Relativity) after considering cosmological symmetries, and $\lambda$-parameters are the coefficients of terms in the Lagrangian. However, my question is strictly mathematical.
So, after I've introduced what I've already tried to do and the clarifications on why do I have that question, I can ask it.
Are there any conventional ways of examining a dynamical system on its behaviour at infinity?

By "finite as the time goes" do you mean you want the trajectories to be bounded as $t \to \infty$, or just that they don't  go to $\infty$ in finite time?

One way to show that all trajectories are bounded as $t \to \infty$ is to find a function $V: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} V(x) = +\infty$ and $$ \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x_i}  \le 0$$
for $|x|$ sufficiently large.
